# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent"

Tags: java, maven

I'm struggling with Maven plugins issues since days now doing a `Maven > Lifecycle > Site`

The errors I'm getting:

- https://codeshare.io/GLXByl

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent
```

I know I'm missing some plugins. I've tried all the solutions in previous posts and many version last and older ones but still missing them and I don't know what I'm missing in my `pom.xml`:

- https://codeshare.io/5MO1Xe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This needs to be added to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
  <artifactId>doxia-site-renderer</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 9):

Apparently you miss certain plugins in your `<build/>`. Add these:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: Where can I see the latest version of these plugins?

Comment: I look it up on MVNRepository, e.g. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-site-plugin — type your `artifactId` into top Search bar, type Enter, inspect result displayed and click the artifact link, you need. You will then see list of all versions of this artifact.

Comment: I only saw the dependency version there. Is this the same as the plugin?

Comment: The column `Version` shows, well, the version. ;-)

Comment: this help, but I don't understand why we need to do this

Comment: @BabyishTank Maven's tasks are performed by so called plugins (code in JAR files). So if you need to call specific task, you need to point the Maven to a plugin that handles this specific task. And this is exactly what we do here. If you read details about given task in its docs it may give you a hint, what plugin(s) needs to be included to make the task work.